# Octave: Can't start GUI after installing from homebrew

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, ui

I installed octave using homebrew.

When I call

```
octave --force-gui
```

I get error:

> octave: GUI features missing or disabled in this build

**Q:** How to make it work in GUI mode?

I also tried

```
brew reinstall octave --with-qt --with-fltk --with-gui
```

like it was suggested in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231799/252061), but it didn't help.

Here is some debug information:

```
$brew info octave
octave: stable 4.4.0 (bottled), HEAD
High-level interpreted language for numerical computing
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index.html
/usr/local/Cellar/octave/4.4.0 (2,173 files, 45.4MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-05-10 at 18:11:38
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/octave.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: gnu-sed ✘, pkg-config ✘
Required: arpack ✔, epstool ✔, fftw ✔, fig2dev ✔, fltk ✔, fontconfig ✔, freetype ✔, gcc ✔, ghostscript ✔, gl2ps ✔, glpk ✔, gnuplot ✔, graphicsmagick ✔, hdf5 ✔, libsndfile ✔, libtool ✔, pcre ✔, portaudio ✔, pstoedit ✔, qhull ✔, qrupdate ✔, readline ✔, suite-sparse ✔, veclibfort ✔
==> Requirements
Build: java >= 1.6 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Comment: Have you tried my answer using MacPorts? MacPorts is similar to Homebrew. Its a package manager specifically for Macs.  If it didn't work please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: @jmh I voted up your solution, though I didn’t verify it as I don’t want to install one more package manager for the purpose of a single app.

Comment: With the brew 5.1.0 release that I just installed, `octave` started the command line version. `octave --force-gui` opened up the gui. I'm on the latest macOS Catalina, but don't think that matters here.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and asked same question. I answered it myself. Remove homebrew version of Octave. Install MacPorts version of Octave. MacPorts is a package manager like Homebrew. Their version of Octave works fine. Instructions for installing MacPorts and Octave are given at MacPorts home page.

Comment: It might not be needed to install another package manager just for Octave. samkass's solution worked for me. Reinstalling said that java is not installed, `homebrew cask` solved it

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me if I first install qt:

```
brew install qt
```

Then install octave with --with-qt:

```
brew install octave --with-qt
```

(Or, if you've already installed it:

```
brew reinstall octave --with-qt
```

)

Comment: The formula no longer `--with-qt` option. I think it is enabled by default with 5.1.0.

Comment: `brew install octave && octave --force-gui` now seems to work. It has `qt` as a dependency so it installed this first. This is for Octave 6.4.0

Answer (score 2):

[Octave.app](http://octave-app.org/) launches OK in GUI mode. [Octave.app installs from a dmg](http://octave-app.org/Download.html). Thus, neither `Homebrew` nor `MacPorts` are required.

The Octave.app has at macOS based testing suite. And when needed, has even applied patches to address [upstream code issues](https://github.com/octave-app/octave-app-bundler/issues/13).

Indeed, Octave.app fixed the very Qt issue(s?) that appeared to be causing problems with the homebrew release. The `brew reinstall octave --with-qt` and a number of other attempts did not work in my case with the current homebrew version.

*`Octave.app` is based on the homebrew build, just with the value add of macOS specific testing, bundling, … and patching.*

Since Octave.app patched the upstream Qt issues which Homebrew had not, I unlinked the homebrew version and installed Octave.app.

```
# if octave exists from either regular Homebrew or dpo/openblas formulae 
brew unlink octave
```